# Linking multiple properties to the same table in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, .net-core

Let me foreword this by saying this is my first real experience with both Entity Framework and relational databases in general. If I am doing it completely wrong, please tell me.

I want my data structured as something like this (Cut down on the "extra" code):

```
Indicators {
    int SomeText1TranslationRef
    List<Translation> SomeText1Translations
    int SomeText2TranslationRef
    List<Translation> SomeText2Translations
}

Measures {
    int SomeText3TranslationRef
    List<Translation> SomeText3Translations
    int SomeText3TranslationRef
    List<Translation> SomeText4Translations
}

Translation {
    Int TranslationID
    String LanguageCode
    String Text
}
```

So in essence, the indicators table would have a list of SomeText1 Translations as well as SomeText2, all joined using the `TranslationID` through the "Ref" properties.

I have the translation properties annotated with `[ForeignKey("....Ref")]`.

I expected this to work magically as the rest of the framework seems to, but instead the translation table gets columns named "SomeText1TranslationRef" and "SomeText2TranslationRef".

Am I doing this wrong?

I am looking at other features of Entity Framework and see an annotation for "InverseProperty". Is it something which may help?

Comment: Can you post your actual code?

Comment: For sure. I avoided doing so as it's a lot more opaque I find: https://gist.github.com/knyzorg/085509cc85dce0cd3f51c4ff6b8ffd34 @Hintham

Comment: I can't really tell from your code what the relations between the various entities are, but most likely you're applying the `ForeignKey` attribute wrong. It can be used in one of three ways:

 - `[ForeignKey(NavigationPropertyName)]` on the foreign key ref property in the dependent entity
 - `[ForeignKey(ForeignKeyPropertyName)]` on the navigation property in the dependent entity
 - `[ForeignKey(ForeignKeyPropertyName)]` on the navigation property in the principal entity.

Comment: Is `public int NameTranslationRefID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("NameTranslationRefID")]
        public ICollection<Translation> Names { get; set; }` Not the second way? @Hintham

Comment: Yes, Indeed. But like I said, I can't really tell how the entities are related, so not sure if they are applied correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short, the caveat is the "Core" part of .Net Core. EF Core does not support convention-over-configuration many-to-many relationships *yet* (See [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1368)).

The only way to achieve this is to manually create the junction tables as Steve suggested. Here is all the information needed: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration

> In previous versions of Entity Framework, this model definition was sufficient for EF to imply the correct type of relationship and to generate the join table for it. In EF Core 1.1.0, it is necessary to include an entity in the model to represent the join table, and then add navigation properties to either side of the many-to-many relations that point to the join entity instead:

The above link will most likely be updated with time so for context purposes, here is the code which goes along with it:

```
public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
} 

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
}

public class BookCategory
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively, using Fluent:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<BookCategory>()
        .HasKey(bc => new { bc.BookId, bc.CategoryId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<BookCategory>()
        .HasOne(bc => bc.Book)
        .WithMany(b => b.BookCategories)
        .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.BookId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<BookCategory>()
        .HasOne(bc => bc.Category)
        .WithMany(c => c.BookCategories)
        .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.CategoryId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% clear on your goal, but if an Indicator can have many Text1 translations and many Text2 translations, then that is 2 many-to-many relationships. Same for Measures. EF will need a join/bridge/junction table for this (IndicatorTranslation and MeasureTranslation). You can explicitly create this table, or let EF do it behind the scenes:

```
Indicator {
    // other indicator fields
    public virtual List<Translation> SomeText1Translations
    public virtual List<Translation> SomeText2Translations
}

Measure {
    // other measure fields
    public virtual List<Translation> SomeText3Translations
    public virtual List<Translation> SomeText4Translations
}

Translation {
    Int TranslationID
    String LanguageCode
    String Text

    // Use inverse attributes or fluent code to tell EF how to connect relationships
    [InverseProperty("SomeText1Translations")]
    public virtual ICollection<Indicator> TranslationForIndicatorText1 { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("SomeText2Translations")]
    public virtual ICollection<Indicator> TranslationForIndicatorText2 { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("SomeText3Translations")]
    public virtual ICollection<Measure> TranslationForMeasureText3 { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("SomeText4Translations")]
    public virtual ICollection<Measure> TranslationForMeasureText4 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Would this not make Translation have multiple needless fields for the text while I just need one?

Comment: No. Translation might have records like `1, English, "My text in english"` and `2, Spanish, "My text in spanish"`. Indicator might have data like `1, My First Indicator` and `2, My second indicator`. A table is created behind the scenes (IndicatorTranslation) that would have IndicatorId and TranslationId containing 1,1 and 1,2 and 2,1 and 2,2.

Comment: Hmm. I'll give it a shot. Is this a good way to handle translations in the first place?

Comment: That's a broad question. You could use [resource strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/globalization-localization/). If you are gong to use a database approach, you could store your translations independently then go retrieve what you need for the selected language in your controller and save them to a viewmodel.

Comment: It's an elegant solution in EF terms, but it should be noted that EF Core doesn't support "behind the scenes" many-to-many tables (yet, hopefully, don't remember). Probably worse, you'll also end up with 4 \*-\*-tables for no other reason but to conform the the capabilities of EF, which might not be... Optimal.  I did not understand the question to require any many to many-tables though, so I could have misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Classe I read into his question that he has 2 text fields in Indicator (and Measure) and he wants various translations for each. So Text1 can have many translations and a translation can be used in any of the 4 text fields. I mention in my comment that it probably makes more sense to compose a viewmodel and lookup the translations in the controller. Design aside, I don't see the issue with 4 join tables - it is still normalized data so no redundancy. Querying for all occurences of a given translation might be a challenge with this particular design.

Comment: I am trying to implement it but am getting a bunch of errors. Could you give me a complete minimal example of it? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @Steve Greene Ah, in that scenario it certainly is the proper solution. I was thinking the "LanguageCode" would pretty much be just be a discriminator (so Id+Code = key), so each translation ref has X amounts of translations in different languages, but still only one per language+id. A situation I tend to find myself in when being to lazy to properly structure (factor out) situations with identical related data for different types, for better or worse :)

Comment: Hmm so basically I am being forced into doing `Measure.MeasureTranslation.Translation.Text` type of deal?

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy to be corrected if I'm wrong since it's nothing I've tried for quite a while, but as far as I'm aware, EF is still not able to create relationships from one property on a type to two different other types, or vice versa, even with constraints that would make it valid.

In your case, you would end up with the 4 navigation properties being required on your translation. (int IndicatorRef1, int IndicatorRef2, int MeasureRef3, int MeasureRef4). Most wouldn't call it a dream scenario.

I asked a similar question a couple of years ago, and have since then sort of concluded that i was foolish trying  to get EF to solve all my problems.

So here's an answer to what you're trying to achieve, and perhaps even a solution to 2 of your questions:

Don't rely on EF handle any scenario. Actually, pretty much don't rely on EF to handle relationships at all other than 1-1, 1-* or *-*. And some forms of inheritance.

In most other cases, you will end up with one navigation property for each type you're trying to reference, with data being populated with nulls for each navigation property but the one specifically targeted.

The good news? You don't have to rely on EF for it. The main advantage of EF is it's productivity. For certain cases, it's still worth leveraging EF, but providing your own methods of productivity. If you want to get a set of indicators with 2 collections of translations based on a ref, simply create a method that provides it.

Something like

```
        public IQueryable<Indicators> SetOfIndicatorsWithTranslations()
        {
            // Untested query that might need some fixing in an actual implementation 
            return ctx.Set<Indicators>().Select(ind => new Indicators() {
                                    Text1Ref= ind.Text1Ref, // whatever the property is 
                                    Text1RefList = ctx.Set<Translation>().Where(t => t.TranslationId == ind.Text1Ref),  
                                    Text2Ref= ind.Text2Ref,  
                                    Text2RefList = ctx.Set<Translation>().Where(t => t.TranslationId == ind.Text2Ref),  
                                });
        }
```

Now that's a query EF will handle for you gracefully.

There are of course a lot more elegant solutions to something like it. The important part is really that it's sometimes worth doing it yourself rather than restricting yourself to the capabilities of your tool of choice. (Well, at least that's the important part that I eventually learned :) )

Comment: It's indeed starting to look like it's not doable in EF. I do not want to tread outside of what EF offers as it's the only thing that's been allowing me to do my job for the last few weeks and I wouldn't want to kick the ladder out of the person who comes after me. Tomorrow I will attempt Steve's solution, otherwise I will try a totally different approach.